# Nodejs stream chaining

Tags: node.js, stream, nodejs-stream

Hello I would like to chain some fileReadStreams, my current use is something like that;

1. spawn a child process
2. create a fileReadStream
3. send file content via pipe(child.stdin)
4. loop back to step 2

I'm trying to send some mp3 files using pipe to ffmpeg, so it can output an infinite hls&mpeg-dash based stream.

PS: I tried `finished` event of writableStream, but if finished gets triggered child.stdin closed by the writableStream. If I pass the flag to not close I never get finished event.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PassThrough streams, the results are not perfect but it's ok in my case. If anyone needs something like this here is how I dealt with it;

```
const {PassThrough} = require('stream');

const pt = new PassThrough();

/* spawn child process */
/* PS: I do not know why direct pipe to ffmpeg does not work in my case throws pipe: Permission denied */
const child = spawn(
    'cat',
    ['|', 'ffmpeg', ...],
    {
        stdio: ['pipe', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
        shell: true
    });

pt.pipe(child.stdin);

/* pass streams to pt stream with end false parameter */
stream1.pipe(pt, { end: false }); /* This also prevents stream1 finished event, but otherwise it would close the pt stream. */
stream2.pipe(pt, { end: false }); /* Or you can handle this part programmatically(loops, generators etc) */
```